# iOS Swift keyboard disable code is not working when I click blank area

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

This is my code. I did everything as same as the learning video. But does not work. I dont know why?

Thanks

```swift
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageLabel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var urunAdiLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var urunBedeniLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var urunFiyatiLabel: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let gestureRecognizer = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(klavyeyiKapat))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }
    
    @IBAction func kaydetButonuTiklandi(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    

    @objc func klavyeyiKapat () {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

[image: My code viewing]

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to instantiate a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` that recognizes a specific type of gesture. You never instantiate a `UIGestureRecognizer`, it's a base class for specific recognizers.

In this case you most probably need `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```swift
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(klavyeyiKapat))
```